# How to change a particular path from the environment variable PATH?

Tags: bash, command-line

I incorrectly declared a variable, and now it has two forward slashes in it. How do I unset/correct it?

`PATH=...ols-1.3-62308//bin:/bin`

Thanks.

Comment: export PATH="stuff" ?

Comment: Please note that variable values changed dynamically are lost once you exit the current shell right. If you need them to be persistent you will need to update your bash profile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this particular example, do nothing: [the double slash is exactly equivalent to a single slash](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/1910/885).

If you really want to remove double slashes: `PATH=${PATH//\/\//\/}`

Removing the first entry: `PATH=${PATH#*:}`
Removing the last entry: `PATH=${PATH%:*}`
Removing an entry from the middle is more fiddly, and not really worth it on the command line.

There are ways to get the value of a variable into the command line editor:

- In zsh, you would simply run `vared PATH`.
- In bash, run `history -s "PATH=$PATH"` to push the assignment into the command history, then press <kbd>Up</kbd> to bring up the last entry and edit it. (Zsh: `print -s PATH=$PATH`)
- In bash, type `PATH=$PATH`, then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Meta</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> (`shell-expand-line`). (Zsh: press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> <kbd>*</kbd> to expand the word at or before the cursor.)

Answer (score 4):

There is a similar post on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/):  [What is the most elegant way to remove a path from the $PATH variable in Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/370047/what-is-the-most-elegant-way-to-remove-a-path-from-the-path-variable-in-bash). Just have a look.

Answer (score 1):

You will want to include the $PATH

if you're using bash you usually want to set something like the line below in your .bashrc file:

`PATH=$PATH:/path/to/new/directory/`

ie.  `$PATH` is your currnet PATH

and `/path/to/new/directory` is the path where the new binaries are stored.

in my case I tend to have some scripts in my $HOME/bin so I would do:
`PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin`

then make sure to source the file to apply the changes to your current shell.

ie.  `source ~/.bashrc`     or    `. ~/.bashrc`